# Is it possible to construct matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $AB$ is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-rank

Let $A$ be an $n \times m$ matrix and let $B$ be an $m \times n$ matrix. Also, let $n$ be less than $m$. Is it possible to construct $A$ and $B$ such that $AB$ is invertible?

I know that $AB$ must have dimensions $n \times n$. If both $A$ and $B$ are full rank, then $AB$ should also be full rank. Thus, $AB$ should be invertible. However, I can't find a line of reason for why $AB$ should also be full rank.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If $A$ is $n\times m$ and $B$ is also $n\times m$ with $n\lt m$, then you cannot calculate $AB$. Did you mean $B$ to be $m\times n$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, yes I did! Apologies for the mistake. I fixed it.

Comment: $AB$ need not be of full rank even if $A$ and $B$ are of full rank; it *can* be, but it doesn’t have to be. I’ve added an example to show that you could even have $AB=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is $n\times m$ and $B$ is $m\times n$, with $m\lt n$, then $AB$ cannot be invertible. If $n\lt m$, then yes, it can be, but it doesn’t *have* to be.

If $n\lt m$, one example would be to let $A$ have first $n$ columns be the $n\times n$ identity and then fill in with zero columns; and let $B$ have first $n$ rows be the $n\times n$ identity, and the rest of the rows be zero. i.e.
$$\begin{align*}
 A &= \left(\begin{array}{ccccccc}
1 & 0 &\cdots &0 & 0 & \cdots &0\\
0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots &0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 0 & \cdots &0\end{array}\right)\\
B&=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & \cdots& 0\\
0 & 1 & \cdots& 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 1\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\end{array}\right).
\end{align*}$$
Then $AB$ is the $n\times n$ identity.

So it is possible for $AB$ to be invertible. However, it need not be invertible *necessarily*. For instance, just move the identity matrix in $A$ one column to the right, and the product of $A$ and $B$ will not be full rank. For  a worst case scenario, take $m=2n$, and let $A$ have $n$ columns of zeros followed by the identity matrix, and leave $B$ the same. Then $A$ and $B$ both have full rank, but $AB$ is the zero matrix.

On the other hand, if $m\lt n$, then note that the rank of $B$ is at most $m$; that means that the rank of $AB$ is at most $m$, and hence cannot equal $n$ (which you would need for $AB$ to be invertible). Alternatively, because $B$ has more columns than rows, there exists a nonzero vector $\mathbf{v}$ such that $B\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$. But then $(AB)\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$, with $\mathbf{v}\neq\mathbf{0}$, which again tells you $AB$ cannot be invertible.

Answer (score 1):

$AB$ need not be invertible. To see this, take\begin{equation*}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*} \begin{equation*}
B = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2\\
2 & 4\\
3 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*} Notice $A$ and $B$ both have full rank, but \begin{equation*}
AB = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
2 & 4 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*} does not.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: My answer adresses the original version of the question.

A short answer: no.  $A$ and $B$ have $m$ columns and $n$ rows respectively, and you let $n < m$ in the question, so the matrix product $AB$ can't even be defined.

Comment: I actually made a mistake in the problem statement - B should be m by n. I fixed it now. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: nvm.  i dunno why another answer got self-deleted.  its argument using rank looked nice at the first glance.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會: Because I had answered with the wrong inequality, and I wanted to fix it without people commenting or downvoting on a mistaken answer.